# How do I bundle data files with a macOS Terminal application?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, terminal

I'm trying to bundle a text file with a macOS command line tool that I'm building. I've added the file to the project, but I can't seem to access it from code. My project looks like this:

[image: Image of the project explorer, with small_names.txt adjacent to main.swift]

And the function I'm using to try and load that data looks like this:

```swift
func loadFile() -> [String] {
    let fileName = "small_names"
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "txt") else {
        print("couldn't open \(fileName)")
        return []
    }
    // load that URL
}
```

However, `url` appears to always be `nil`. When I run the program, I get `couldn't open small_names` printed out.

What do I need to do to ship this file with my program? How do I get its url from code?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the text file appear in Targets > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources? That's the list of items in the bundle and they aren't always added automatically.

Comment: Hm. That build phase was missing. I added it and now it's staying checked in the "Target Membership" value in the File Inspector, but it's still getting nil from `Bundle.main.url`

Comment: Weird. I added small_names.txt to a project, ran your code and it found the url without a problem. Maybe try it in a fresh project?